# How to verify that AUCTeX works with latest (2017) TeXLive (actually, MacTeX)?

Tags: auctex, mactex

Last year I installed MacTeX 2016. Today I've installed MacTeX 2017. I did not delete the 2016 version, nor did I take any explicit steps to switch to the 2017 version except running the MacTeX 2017 installer and accepting all defaults.

My TeX editor is Emacs+AUCTeX. How can I verify that AUCTeX works with the 2017 version rather than with the 2016 one?

I've also installed the `ebib` package for handling `.bib` files, and would like to verify that `ebib` works with the 2017 version.

---

OS: macOS Sierra Version 10.12.5
Emacs: GNU Emacs 25.1.1
AUCTeX: 11.90.0
Ebib: ? [I don't know how to check the version.]

Comment: what do you mean by verify here? can't you just check your current documents still work? (

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Even if they do still work - how can I tell that it isn't because they still use the old version?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: For example, I'd like to verify that the LaTeX engine that AUCTeX uses is the one from the 2017 distribution. I'd like to verify that if I use `luatex`, it'll be the latest version. I'd like to verify that the `makeindex` engine is the latest. I'd like to verify that the `pdf` rendering engines are the latest. I'd like to verify that the bibliography engine is the latest.

Comment: the log file of any tex file shows the version in the banner and in the paths used by all the packages.

Comment: or jut `mv /usr/local/texlive/2016 /usr/local/texlive/2016-moved-out-of-the-way`  then if things still work, you're using the new one in `/usr/local/texlive/2017`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: OK. This is a good idea. By the way, when I opened my `/usr/local/texlive` folder I noticed that it contained another folder beside `2016` and `2017`, namely `texmf-local`. Do you know what it's for, and whether it belongs to the 2016 distribution or to the 2017 distribution?

Comment: You should update AUCTeX to the latest ELPA version available, 11.90.2, it has a fix for TeX Live 2017.

Comment: that is texmf-local is for _your_ local additions if you put stuff in there it is usable in tl2016 and tl2017 and next year it'll still be in the path for tl2018.

Comment: it is possible to decide to have a texmf-local inside each 20xx folder, I don't know if MacTeX install script offers a way. But the texlive install script does. A priori you don't need to worry. It is theoretically possible though that if you add things to texmf-local, they may become obsolete or create problems in future years. Personally I keep the things which I really want to keep over the years in my home (~/Library/texmf) hierarchy. It makes more sense than texmf-local which is though out for multi-users.